# Looking for a game with both faction intrigue and dungeon delving

Tags: game-recommendation

I've been meaning to play a campaign where my player will be able to experience two spheres: dungeon exploration, as underling task to get some magic items etc., and some political intrigue, navigating the hierarchy of the organization who hired them and their concurrent.

The setting is a custom med-fan one, and the players will be acting around one of the big event of the world, which happened after much political conflict, fighting for influence between guilds and sects in a big city. They will work for one (or more) of these groups, and I want them to be able to make their place in this web while the intrigue progress.

Ideally, I would like a system with a flexible magic system, but as long as there is some magic in it, it will be okay. Also, I would like a system with some crunch, no something too rule light.

To summarize:

- Rules for interaction with, between and inside a faction (I already have the setting)
- Still allowing for a D&D like adventure experience (combat, dungeon exploration etc.)
- It should work with a medieval-fantastic setting. If necessary, I will do the work to adapt the system to the setting, but being easily extensible is a plus.
- Idem for a magic system, the setting have some specific rules for magic, but they can be flexible outside specific situation.

Systems I've already thought about:

- D&D 3.5 / Pathfinder: from my experience, the social/influence rules of these game are not that important. Maybe I missed something about them, only having the base rules.
- Reign Enrichidon: I tried it for a bit, it is a good system, but do not help much for influence of a person inside a faction.
- FATE Core: Everything is possible with FATE, but I would like something with more rigid rules

Right now, I'm considering toning down the faction elements of the campaign and switching to a customized Call of Cthulhu, moving the focus to a more occult play style, but I am still interested in answers.

Comment: Hi there. For the political side, are you looking for a system with strong mechanics for handling the interaction of largescale NPC-managed factions? Or are you looking for a setting with a large number of interacting political factions you can use in a campaign?

Comment: Oh! You're new. in that case, welcome to RPG.SE! To ensure that the questions we get can always have a reasonably-objectively-best answer, we have some specific requirements for system-recommendation questions. You can read them here: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic/1071#1071 Once you've read those, I recommend editing your question to clarify exactly what it is you need; At present, your question's criteria might not be specific enough.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the link, I should have checked meta before posting, but I was a bit in a rush when I did it. I will update it as soon as possible

Comment: Okay, let me know if you need some more details, I know recommendations are tricky on SE.

Comment: If you clean this up to ask for specific requests, I would also like to know the recommendations made!

Comment: When it comes to 3.5 DND having access to only the base rules can be troublesome. See if you can get ahold of these 7 books at the bare minimum. Players handbook I & II Dungeon masters guide I &II magic item compendium spell compendium and the rules compendium. (The last simply for easy rule lookup) the DMG II has an entire section on factions and politics.

Comment: After those its just finding additional rule sets and variants to install from other books. I seem to recall a taint/reputation system from unearthed arcana that might come in handy